# c# win8 HtmlAgilityPack trouble

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Hello I want to parse HTML from a website for metro app. I saw some tutorials about HtmlAgilityPack and I decided that it is kinda easily. But when I started project, I saw that some methods or references are not included in HtmlAgilityPack library as tutorials I watched.

Example :

in the tutorial video, it says:

> HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
>
> HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("url");

in my HtmlAgilityPack library, I can't see a method called HtmlWeb.Load

Example 2 :

in tutorial video, it says :

> var res = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("element names");

in my library, there isn't a method called "SelectNodes" in HtmlDocument.DocumentNode

Am I missing something? I installed HtmlAgilityPack in NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

No, you missed nothing. The metro (Windows RT) platform doesn't support all of Windows .NET features.

XPATH for example is not supported, and since the XPATH feature (SelectNodes comes with this feature) of Html Agility Pack is based on the .NET one, it's not supported in Html Agility Pack for Windows RT.